# How to convert micostation v8 dgn to IFS in FME?

Tags: dgn, fme-form, bim

I have a 3D model saved in dgn format as V8. This may be initially created in Bentley AECOsim. I can't able to convert it to IFC format?

I added reader as dgn(v8) and writer as IFC in FME workbench. It converts some feature in a particular layer but not all. In log it seems it successfully read all feature but couldn't write all. What ever the feature got write is not view-able in FMEinspector.

Can anyone point in good direction?

Comment: look like the ifc_representation_identifier needs to be set in the writer you may need to expose some dgn attributes, what is your workspace like?

Comment: "Features have been recorded at every stage of the translation.To inspect the recorded features,.double-click the feature count numbers on connections and ports." But output is not viewable saying "There is No Geometry in this view".